# Avoid subscriber to receive published message (via Hazelcast Pub/Sub)

Tags: publish-subscribe, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast library and more specifically the pub/sub feature. Is it possible for a member who is subscribed to a topic not to receive its own published message to the corresponding topic, but all other subscribed members to receive it?

More specificaly, lets say we have three members all subscribed to topic "myTopic"

when for instance member1.publish(message), to receive it only members 2 and 3 and not member1

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create different topics where different sets of subscribers are registered. Hazelcast does not have any filter techniques on those subscribers.